# Installing Kate editor in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kate

I recently updated my Ubuntu to 16.04. I need to install Kate editor but it doesn't appear in the Ubuntu Software. Is there any way to install Kate Editor in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Oh.. It was my mistake. ;) Fixed it now..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try opening a terminal window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and typing the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kate
```

Please let me know if this was helpful or if you run into any problems.

Nick

Comment: It also worked in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of [Universe](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&keywords=kate) so should be available on an updated system that has universe enabled.

So ...

- Do you have this disabled perhaps? (You can add it with `sudo add-apt-repository universe`).
- Did you install Ubuntu 16.04 and not update the system yet? (`sudo apt update` to update it).

And ...

```
sudo apt install kate
```

should install it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the [appimage version](https://kate-editor.org/get-it/) because I found the ubuntu version is different (e.g. doesn't have the regex search functionality).

The way I did that: [see this Q/A on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404289/how-do-i-redirect-from-a-built-in-bin-to-execute-an-appimage-instead/55404622).